# Am I able to scan a document and extract certain words?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a word document that has tags denoted by "[[]]" for example [[sqlscript1]]. I would like to scan the document and display sqlscript1 in a text box. Am I able to only read words containing [[]]?

Comment: @SystemDown How exactly is processing a Word document OCR? Word isn't a graphical format.

Comment: Ach you're right. I saw scan and my mind jumped to OCR. My bad.

Comment: I'd try looking at [the OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx) for this. (I haven't actually worked with it though, so caveat emptor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [load the content of the Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100019/reading-word-file-in-c-sharp) into memory. Second, use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to find the tags denoted by double square brackets (required pattern: `"\[\[(?<tag>[^\]]*)\]\]"`).

Answer (score 1):

As millimoose said, the OpenXML SDK is what you are looking for.  We do something just like this in document generation for dynamic powerpoint slides.  The SDK give you the ability to have a programmatic handle on the object model of the document in question and change/search/manipulate it as needed.

Comment: Assuming the document is Word 2007 and above, this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the Text from the Word Document with the Interop-DLLs.
Take a look a this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173188(v=vs.80).aspx

Then read the file with something like this:

```
object file = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Answer.doc";

Word.Application wordObject = new Word.ApplicationClass();
wordObject.Visible = false;

object nullobject = Missing.Value;
Word.Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open
    (ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);

String strLine;
bool bolEOF = false;

docs.Characters[1].Select();

int index = 0;
do
{
    object unit = Word.WdUnits.wdLine;
    object count = 1;
    wordObject.Selection.MoveEnd(ref unit, ref count);

    strLine = wordObject.Selection.Text;
    richTextBox1.Text += ++index + " - " + strLine + "\r\n"; //for our understanding

    object direction = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    wordObject.Selection.Collapse(ref direction);

    if (wordObject.Selection.Bookmarks.Exists(@"\EndOfDoc"))
        bolEOF = true;
} while (!bolEOF);

docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
wordObject.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
docs = null;
wordObject = null;
```

Source: [is there a way to read a word document line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924056/is-there-a-way-to-read-a-word-document-line-by-line)

Now copy each line into theinto a variable and use this Regex-Command to check for your pattern:

```
Regex.Match(MYTEXT, @"\[[([^)]*)\]]").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: For extracting data, I would look into OpenXML SDK over Interop. OpenXML is way faster, and Interop is limited to work on a user machine, and should be avoided for any server-side work for instance.